# Paste values using range function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using this code to paste values for a range but I started facing issues whenever my data is in a million or more line numbers, I wanted to break the range and run the same code in 4/5 parts (loops), can some one help me with it

```
Range("F14:J14").Select
Selection.Copy
With ActiveSheet
RowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Range("F14:J14").Select
Selection.Copy

Range("f15:J" & RowCount).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("f15:J" & RowCount).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("f15:J" & RowCount).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Consider better description of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, copying very large number of cells is problematic, so processing the data in blocks is a good idea.

That said, relying on `Select` and `Copy` `PasteSpecial` is also problematic.

I would suggest this alternative

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim rSrc As Range
    Dim rDst As Range
    Dim rBlk As Range
    Dim RowCount As Long
    Dim CopyRowStart As Long
    Dim CopyRowNum As Long

    ' Set number of rows to process at a time
    CopyRowNum = 100000

    ' Set references to source and Destination ranges
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rSrc = .Range("F14:J14")
        RowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rDst = .Range("F15:J" & RowCount)
    End With

    ' Copy data in blocks
    CopyRowStart = 0
    Set rBlk = rDst.Resize(CopyRowNum)
    Do While CopyRowStart + CopyRowNum <= rDst.Rows.Count
        ' Copy formulas
        rBlk.Formula = rSrc.Formula
        ' Convert to values
        rBlk.Value = rBlk.Value
        ' Move to next block
        If rBlk.Row + CopyRowNum + CopyRowStart - 1 > rDst.Row + rDst.Rows.Count - 1 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        Set rBlk = rBlk.Offset(CopyRowNum, 0)
        CopyRowStart = CopyRowStart + CopyRowNum
        DoEvents
    Loop
    ' Copy remaining rows
    If rBlk.Row + CopyRowNum <= rDst.Row + rDst.Rows.Count - 1 Then
        Set rBlk = rBlk.Resize(rDst.Row + rDst.Rows.Count - rBlk.Row - CopyRowNum)
        Set rBlk = rBlk.Offset(CopyRowNum, 0)
        rBlk.Formula = rSrc.Formula
        rBlk.Value = rBlk.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Note, the rather convoluted range size calculation are designed to avoid exceeding the size of the sheet, when the number of rows nears the end of the sheet (1,048,576 rows)